# Can iOS 7 folders and dock be skinned to be totally black?

Tags: dock, ios

I've just upgraded to iOS 7 on an iPhone 4S. I prefer a completely *black* wallpaper, but I noticed that making it so will turn the backgrounds of folders and the dock *grey*.

[image]

I am looking for a combined wallpaper color and folder/dock background to make them as close as possible to all black. If someone has a jailbreak solution, that's great, but that won't work for me as I prefer not to change the OS in that way.

Are there solutions to achieve this visual effect?

Comment: There is no jailbreak for iOS 7 yet. Just be patient…

Comment: @daviesgeek Just to be clear: I am specifically asking for a non-JB solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is really no way to do what you are asking. Both the dock and the folder backgrounds are a result of the "frosted glass" effect that Apple has introduced with iOS 7. No matter what color background you are using, the dock and folder backgrounds are going to lighten and blur whatever is behind them to achieve that effect.

Comment: This is a great explanation of what seems to be intended as well as a clue on what would be needed - to adjust the "transparency" of the overlay to make it closer to black than white.

Answer (score 2):

`Settings > General > Accessibility > Increase Contrast: ON` goes some way to reduce the transparency effects, particularly in Control Center, but the grey boxes you refer to are essentially an average of your background wallpaper.  Switch to a largley blue one, and they will use a colour averaged blue with added transparency for them.  There's no supported way to set an arbitrary colour.

Answer (score 0):

I kept having this issue where mine was gray. I went into `Settings` (Settings->-General->Accessibility) and found that high contrast was on. I switched it off and the dock became more transparent. It's not going to be entirely black, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into General > Accessibility > Invert Colours - However it makes all your icons look awful, but the backgrounds on texts, options, settings etc.. all look fantastic!

I agree it would be better to be able to switch this to a black background skin, than white, I don't really like the white look, but maybe it's just something I'm not used to just yet.

Answer (score -1):

I took a picture of a black piece of glossy paper and then used that photo as my wallpaper. Makes it look good as I have a Black iPhone 5

Comment: How does this change the grey dock and folder colors? ( your statement might be true aesthetically, but we try to have answers address the question at hand)