# Can I change the color of the folders in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to change the folder colors on my home screen. Can it be done?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get a black background? Even with a black picture the background colour is still grey

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102222/can-ios-7-folders-and-dock-be-skinned-to-be-totally-black - and no, there is no jailbreak or way to alter the transparency to achieve a true black effect.

Answer (score 2):

The folder colors change based upon the background image. So, in that sense, yes, you can. However, they do not have their own UI element to allow you to edit their colors independently.

Answer (score 0):

The folder colors, dock, lock screen slide to unlock, as well as the passcode buttons all change based on the background image. That is the only way to change their color, but like Dave mentioned, there is no way to change their colors independently.